# How to use customized icon for Firefox omnibox search suggestion

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions, search-suggestion, omnibox

I want to my Firefox extension could use Firefox omnibox and return user some suggestions when input changed.

At current stage, the omnibox could give me some suggestions, but the icon of the suggestion is still default instead of icon of the website. I already set my extension icon in manifest.json and size of icon is 16px by 16px and 32px by 32px with 7kb.

Should I set suggestion icon somewhere else?

I follow the example from this: https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/firefox-code-search

Comment: This may be a Firefox bug since my omnibox code works fine with an icon in Chrome, but no icon in Firefox.